# Getting list of subfolders name and files name in android source package

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I'm developing an android application that store sql files to update the sqlite database. And that sql script will run when user push certain button. This is where i put my sql files

[image: Where i put my sql files]

So far i've been using this solution to run my script:
First, mapping my update to resource as update.xml

```
<resources>    

    <string name="update_list">
        v2_9_11
    </string>

    <string-array name="v2_9_11">
        <item>1_AlterTable_wapactivity</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

And get the sql script inside the file with this method :

```
private void runScript(String version_name){
        try{
            String[] sql_list = mGap.getResources().getStringArray(getArrayIdentifier(mGap, version_name));
            for (String sql : sql_list) {
                InputStream in =  getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/ods/scm/script/update/"+version_name+"/"+sql+".sql");
                Reader fr = new InputStreamReader(in, "utf-8");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String s="";
                String baris;
                while((baris=br.readLine())!=null){
                    s+=baris;
                 }
                mDbHelper.executeStatement(s);
            }
            insertUpdate(version_name);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I get the String version_name and String[ ] sql_list file name from update.xml.
The problem is, i want to get version_name ( in this case v2_9_11 as subfolder name from folder update ) and sql file name ( in this case 1_AlterTable_wapactivity.sql ) without mapping it in update.xml. Can ayone help me?

**EDIT**
Or can anyone direct me how to automatically mapping it to update.xml when build the application?

Comment: In the first line of for loop what does `getClass()` refers to, i.e. to which class it refers (full name with package please)?

Comment: getClass() refers to Update.class. It's in package com.ods.scm.setting

Comment: where is the version `v2_9_11` from? Is the version identical with your Android app version in manifest?

Comment: @alijandro yes. it is identically with my app version in manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry all, i just now put it in bounty but i'm able to resolve it by myself by the short time after i put it in bounty. Anyway, my solution is to open the apk file that inside the android device (data/app/....apk) as a zip stream. Then list all the file that start with `com/ods/scm/script/update`. Here my method to get all file that start with it :

```
public ArrayList openApk(String filePath){
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  FileInputStream fis = null;
  ZipInputStream zipIs = null;
  ZipEntry zEntry = null;
  try {
      fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
      zipIs = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
      while((zEntry = zipIs.getNextEntry()) != null){
        if(zEntry.getName().startsWith("com/ods/scm/script/update/"))
          list.add(zEntry.getName());
      }
      zipIs.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: It's a good implementation. Android development tool keep your sql files directory structure unchanged and package into APK file.

Comment: yes. but i dont know about proguard. if i use proguard, is my sql file getting encrypted?

Comment: No, proguard only processing your code. Your sql files remain untouched.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you put the .sql file in `assets` folder. By doing that, you are free to manipulate your file with File IO API.

Comment: sorry, but its my company requirement to put that sql file in src package