# Local test, open a file in the "assets" directory

Tags: android, junit, android-testing

First, I am talking about "test", not "androidTest". I created a test data file and put it in "test"'s asset directory. Android Studio shows that it belongs to the test, not AndroidTest, as below:

[image]

Now, how can I open that file in a local test? I guess I could specify the full path or a relative path, but I think that there probably is a way to specify file name only, like the androidTest example:

```
getInstrumentation()
.getContext()
.getResources()
.getAssets()
.open("test.txt");
```

---

PS: In case there is no such convenient way, I have tested things a little bit and the test's working directory is the "app" directory, so the following code worked.

```
val f = File(".\\src\\test\\assets\\test.txt");
val text = f.readText();
```

Comment: Short answer no you can't. But what are you trying to test? We could offer some work arounds.

Comment: @Blundell I am trying to test part of my Android app that does not use any Android framework. So, I don't have to test it on a device using androidTest which is slow because it has to launch an emulator. Android Studio generates two kinds of tests by default for a project, and one of which is "test" that runs on my computer, not on a device.

Comment: The assets folder is part of the Android framework. Could you duplicate the file you are needing to a unit test resource folder? or make an abstraction and mock the file to read to look in a different location for the test

Comment: @Blundell Actually, I don't have to use the "assets" directory, all I want to providing a text file, and I thought I was supposed to use the "assets" directory because Android Studio seemed to recognise it. So, what is the recommended way to provide a file to a local test of an Android project? What or where is the "test resource folder"?

Comment: Great! Even easier then. Use `/src/test/resources` (here's a random example I googled https://howtoprogram.xyz/2017/01/17/read-file-and-resource-in-junit-test/)

Answer (score 0):

Given `assets` is a part of the android framework, and unit tests run explicitly outside of the android framework, what you're looking for instead is `resources` instead of `assets`.

Tutorial: https://howtoprogram.xyz/2017/01/17/read-file-and-resource-in-junit-test/

But notice, you may want one directory to hold files for both unitTest *and* androidTest. Here's an example of one way to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48607306/1399483